# input color value not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to change color in `<input type=color>`

```html
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            Color: <input type="color" id="color">
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $("#color").val("#000080"); // Initial setup

            $("#color").change(function () {
                console.log($("#color").val())
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, when I pick a color in the color picker, `$("#color").val()` keeps outputting the initial value of `#000080` instead of the updated color value.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: `.change()` fires only when the the color picker has closed and/or a color has been selected

Comment: @DacreDenny Yeah, `.change()` gets fired as the console can print the value

Comment: Are you wanting `.change()` to fire when ever the color picker is sampled by the user? or only after the user has selected a color?

Comment: @DacreDenny only after the user has selected a color meaning the user need to click "OK"

Comment: @BenTinner I do not understand your issue, the color picker works this way only, when you select something click ok then only the change fires, and in there you are getting correct value.

Comment: @BenTinner What exactly are you experiencing ?? cuz I tested the code and it works fine.. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Strange... the code snippet works for me too, but the code in my website does not... i may plan to post up the file, but problem is it uses Flask to fill up on a lot of stuff therefore i can't just rip and post cause it will definitely not run

Also it seems that when I do `$($0).val()` using the chrome dev tools and pointing to the picker, it returns the updated value but not `$("#color").val()`